# Проблема с запросом на выборку.

Tags: массивы, php

Перевожу запрос в массив вот так

```
while ( $arr[] = mysql_fetch_array($transactions) );
```

Из-за [] у меня лишний ключ в массиве создается. Убираю [] - и массива нет и ошибок не пишет.

Comment: Ох... Вы хоть понимаете что значит []?

Comment: О. Я как раз так и переделал только что. =) Работает=) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@RattleSneyk](/users/19483/rattlesneyk), смысл итерации в том, чтобы подставлять данные в указанную переменную при каждом прохождении итерируемого блока кода. При каждом цикле в `$arr[]` (в текущем коде) будет записываться результат `mysql_fetch_array()` - даже если это false. Вы, наверное, хотели такую реализацию:

```
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($transactions)) {
    $arr[] = $temp;
}
```

При этом в последней проверке `$temp` перезапишется, но не попадет в `$arr`.

Answer (score 2):

На последней итерации, когда выборка закончилась, функция mysql_fetch_array($transactions) вернёт false, который запишется в массив $arr[].

После этого будет выполнена проверка на окончание цикла, то есть на последнее значение выражения

```
$arr[] = mysql_fetch_array($transactions)
```

которое будет равно false. Это будет признаком выхода из итерации.

Чтобы избежать попадания false в итоговый массив, воспользуйтесь временной переменной

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($transactions) && $arr[]=$row);
```

Это классический пример с собеседования по PHP.